# Construct a polynomial function with the given graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, graphing-functions

[image: graph]

Where does one begin? I can see that the zeros are -5, -3, 0, and 4? Is that correct so far?

Comment: I only see zeros at $-4,3,5$.

Comment: Nope, not at all. The zeros are $5,3$ and $-4$.

Comment: @copper.hat ah sorry, zeros are only where the line touches the x-axis correct?

Comment: Yes, zeros are the points where the function has value zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's use the fact that the graph has zeros at $5,3$ and $-4$. Given the window, we may as well assume these are the **only** zeros of the polynomial. Note also that we don't have any "flattening" near the zeros, so the zeros must be of multiplicity $1$. Hence, the polynomial is $$p(x)=a(x-5)(x-3)(x+4)$$ for some constant $a$. We can use the fact that $p(0)=3$ to solve for $a$, and then expand if we desire.

Comment: I tried inputting your answer, and it is not working sadly. Could we be overlooking something?

Comment: That works! You got the 1/20 by dividing the 3 into 60?

Comment: Well, my formula $p(x)=a(x-5)(x-3)(x+4)$ gives an infinite family of polynomials, so that isn't enough (on its own) to get the answer. Using the fact that we need $p(0)=3$, we have $$3=p(0)=a(0-5)(0-3)(0+4)=a\cdot(-5)\cdot(-3)\cdot(4)=60a,$$ so it follows that $a=\frac1{20}$, so our desired polynomial is $$p(x)=\frac1{20}(x-5)(x-3)(x+4).$$ Does that fit the graph you're looking for?

Comment: Precisely, Tyler! (Sorry for the deletion and repost of my comment. I ran out of time to edit it.)

Answer (score 1):

> Where does one begin? I can see that the zeros are -5, -3, 0, and 4? Is that correct so far?

No, that is not correct.

The zeros are points where $y = 0$, and it appears to me that none of the points you mentioned are actually zeroes of the function.

This graph has $3$ points where $y = 0$, so by the fundamental theorem of algebra, you know that the polynomial will have degree $3$ (or higher, since there may also be complex roots).

You can use the existence of local minimum and maximum points on the graph to construct a polynomial that will have the same extrema. It is a simple application of differential calculus.

Comment: Based on your inspection of the graph, where ***precisely*** is the local maximum? the local minimum?

Comment: Using my super glasses, I can see that the local extrema are at $\frac{1}{3}(4 \pm \sqrt{67})$.

Comment: I see your point. The solution was much more simple than I realized, and your answer is (obviously) correct.

Comment: Well, it isn't necessarily correct. It's just the best we can do with the information we can clearly discern.

Comment: Well, we can pick another point to convince ourselves. $p(-5)=-4$.

Comment: Fair enough, @copper.hat. Of course, this could be a polynomial of arbitrarily high degree chosen to fit all the (finitely many) points in the given window that we think are "obvious".

Comment: :-). I was using Occam's sunglasses...