# Can all graphs be expressed as a function i.e. $f(x)=y$?

Tags: functions, curves

Is there a function for every possible graph? If not, why not? Let it be continuous and with domain of all real numbers.

Comment: Once you say "domain," you are already assuming it is a function.

Comment: How are you defining a "graph"? If it's a collection of ordered pairs $G$ such that for $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)\in G$, $x_1 = x_2$ implies $y_1 = y_2$, then we could just define $f(x) = y$ for all $(x, y)\in G$.

Comment: Your edit has totally changed the question.  A function is defined as a relation that has only one ordered pair for each element of the domain.  As such the answer is yes, regardless of whether it is continuous.  There is no guarantee that it will be what you think of as a "proper function" (from a previous version).

Comment: @RossMillikan I highly suspect what OP *wanted* to ask was if every curve corresponded to a polynomial (given the title example)

Comment: @Paul: one can speak of the domain of a relation as the set of first elements of the ordered pairs that comprise it.  I agree OP is not into such subtleties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say I draw a random curve (assuming it can be infinitely thin), can I find a proper function for it? Let the curve be continuous and with its domain of all real numbers.

There's two cases here. After you've drawn your curve (lets refer to your curve as $\Gamma_f$, for brevity's sake) in $\mathbb{R}^2$, attempt to find somewhere where can draw a vertical line that intersects your curve twice.

1. If you found a vertical line that intersects $\Gamma_f$ twice, there is no such function.
2. If you are unable to find such a vertical line, then there exists a function.

Let's elaborate now. First, note that a function is a "mapping" from one set to another (in this case, it is from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$). Functions that go from $A \to B$ have one crucial requirement:
$$(\forall a \in A)(\exists ! b \in B) \qquad f(a)=b$$
in English, this translates to "for every element $a$ in $A$, there's only one $b$ in $B$ such that $f(a)=b$". That is, you can't have the element $a$ be mapped to two elements simultaneously, saying "$f(a)=b_1, b_2$" in this case is nonsensical. This is why if #1 was the case, then the curve $\Gamma_f$ does not correspond to a function.

Now let's look at the second case. Here, your curve $\Gamma_f$ corresponds to a function *because it fits the requirements*. Doesn't even need to be continuous, if you threw random dots all over the place *then $\Gamma_f$ still corresponds to a function*.

Now of course this function cannot be described with a polynomial if it is just a collection of points, you would have to describe it explicitly. For instance,
the mapping $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$f= \{ (1,1), \ (2, 5), \ (8,9) \}$$
*is a function.* We'd have $f(1)=1, f(2)=5,$ and $f(8)=9$. As for $f(25)$? That's undefined. Regardless, *$f$ is still a function.*

And that is why if #2 is your case, then your curve $\Gamma_f$ corresponds to a function.

Comment: Now it definitely makes sense. Thank you kindly, Andrew! :)

Comment: @maliiaButterfly Very happy I could help!

Comment: So lets say it is continuous and it passes the vertical test, how do we write down the function? Is there any software or anything that could do it?

Comment: @maliiaButterfly Take a look at [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229514/construct-a-polynomial-function-with-the-given-graph). Also, in regards to software doing it, read up on [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Definition).

Comment: @maliiaButterfly If the graph is very smooth(analytic) it can be expressed in a finite or infinite(Taylor expansion) combination of polynomials. Even when it's discontinuous, other generalized expressions involving rational functions could be found. But in general you can't expect your function to have an elementary expression; that is, maybe(if we consider all possibilities, most probably) it can't be expressed by any finite or infinite combination of {powers and roots of x, exponential/logarithmic/trigonometric/rational/irrational functions} that have explicit(closed) algebraic expression.

Comment: Thanks, Hyobin!

Comment: @maliiaButterfly:  There is a huge difference in having a polynomial that approximates your function and having a polynomial that agrees with it.  There are countably many polynomials and continuum many continuous functions, so almost every continuous function is not polynomial.

Comment: @RossMillikan I was trying to actually find on Google continuous functions don't have a polynomial (including Taylor Series) representation. Would you happen to know any off the top of your head/could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Technically $\sin x$ does not have a polynomial representation because the series is infinite.  It is well approximated by the Taylor series over any interval if you take enough terms, but any finite number of terms does not equal it.  Another classic is $e^{-1/x}$ for $x \gt 0$ and $0$ for $x \le 0$.  It is continuous at $0$ and all derivatives are $0$, but the positive side is not identically zero.  The Taylor series at $0$ is identically zero.